# How to import a function to test?

Tags: javascript, testing

I am learning how to test Javascript code in Vanilla Javascript so I am following a tutorial. My project structure looks like this:

- Modules/File.js,File2.js (each file contains a function I want to test)
- app.js (a file for testing which works together with test.js file)
- index.html
- index.js (currently I keep my main code there)
- test.html (I use it to run test, according to the tutorial)
- test.js (this is where I describe tests)

I want to be able to import functions from File.js, and File2.js in app.js, so I can run tests. How do I achieve that?
P.S. I am using es6 modules import/export. But I would like to see how can I run imported functions for test. Maybe using $myapp global variable for it since thats how its done in the tutorial.

test.js:

```
   (function () {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * test function
   * @param {string} desc
   * @param {function} fn
   */
  function it(desc, fn) {
    try {
      fn();
      console.log('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', '\u2714 ' + desc);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('\n');
      console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', '\u2718 ' + desc);
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  function assert(isTrue) {
    if (!isTrue) {
      throw new Error()
    }
  }

  it('test if its a string', function () {
    assert($myapp.isValidString(2))
  })

})();
```

app.js file:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  // Create a global variable and expose it to the world
  var $myapp = {};
  self.$myapp = $myapp;

  $myapp.isValidString = function (value) {
    return typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String;
  }
  
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to import JS functions from one file into another file.

ES6 introduced the module's functionality which allows the import/export of Javascript functions between different files.

Below is a simple example:

```
// helloworld.js

export function helloWorld() {
    return 'Hello World!';
}

// main.js

import helloWorld from './helloworld.js';

console.log(helloWorld());
```

Comment: I am already using es6 modules, but I need some examples how can I run functions in test file since test accesses files through global variable.